Google Sheets QUERY Issue When Name Includes '
I have a QUERY that searches through names of one column and tells me which row of another column that same name occurs. This has worked perfectly for me, however I have experienced for the first time an issue where if the name contains the symbol ' it messes up the QUERY statement. Is there a work around to avoid the ' from throwing off the other 's in the statement?
This is the exact Query Below
=IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:A, ROW(A:A)}, "SELECT Col2 where Col1 = '"&B4&"' LIMIT 1", 0)), -1)

And an Example that is throwing it off is
A            |     B.        |C
Larry O'Brien| Person B      |2
Person B.    | Larry O'Brien |#VALUE!

Are there any modifications I can make to the above function to allow it to still work when names include '
I would like to just throw in that I did use VLOOKUP(MATCH()) previously however I needed an extra statement for the full logic.
My full statement would be along the lines of
=IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:C, ROW(A:C)}, "SELECT Col4 where Col1 = '"&B4&"' AND Col3 = '"&D4&"' LIMIT 1", 0)), -1)
I have also tried Substitute() to get rid of the ' symbol but it does not seem to let me Substitute on "Col4" without breaking the statement


Alternatively you may try with:
=xmatch(B4,A:A)


My concern with that is how would I be able to have a second statement in there.
If your above statement matches the names how would I be able to do another statement concurrently of xmatch(C4, D:D) where the D and A are the same row
This is what inevitably led me to QUERY's which have been successful besides the (') symbol

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

I will be sure to do that next time, I did just have an "aha" moment and realized I could move the Substitute over to search without the ' messing things up. I appreciate your time and effort to help me get this resolved

Something like this should workout for extra column thing =index(xmatch(B4&D4,A:A&C:C))

Wow, that works and is much cleaner than what I have, thank you. I currently have my QUERY working but if it gives any other issues I will be sure to use this instead.

I Realized that I could just put the SUBSTITUTE() in the Query range instead of trying to put substitute on the "Col2"
This is the finished working statement
=IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({SUBSTITUTE(A:A, "'", ""), ROW(A:A)}, "SELECT Col2 where LOWER(Col1) = LOWER('"&SUBSTITUTE(B4, "'", "")&"') LIMIT 1", 0)), -1)
